# Flutter Android - Retrieve file from intent

Tags: android, flutter

Hello I have registered a custom file extension for my Flutter app.

When I click on a file with this custom extension my app opens. Now I am accessing the retrieved file like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   handleOpenFileUrl(intent)
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
   super.onNewIntent(intent)
   handleOpenFileUrl(intent)
}

private fun handleOpenFileUrl(intent: Intent?) {
   val p = intent?.data?.path
   if (p != null) intentPath = p;
}
```

Now I am facing these problems:

1. The `intentPath` sometimes resolves as `"/device_storage/0/Documents/..."` and sometimes as `"/external/file/<random number>"`.
2. How can I retrieve the file in my Flutter app and read its content?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:

You have to use the ContentResolver to get an InputStream for the file and temporarely save it to the cache directory:

```
private fun handleOpenFileUrl(intent: Intent?) {
    val uri: Uri? = intent?.data
    if (uri == null) return

    var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
    val path = context.cacheDir.absolutePath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".themis"
    val file = File(path)
    if (!file.exists()) {
      file.parentFile?.mkdirs()
      try {
        fos = FileOutputStream(path)
        try {
          val out = BufferedOutputStream(fos)
          val `in`: InputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) ?: return
          val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
          var len = 0
          while (`in`.read(buffer).also { len = it } >= 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len)
          }
          out.flush()
        } finally {
          fos.fd.sync()
        }
        openFileUrl = file.path;
      } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        try {
          fos?.close()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
        } catch (ex: NullPointerException) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

With the `openFileUrl` you can then access the file in your Flutter app.